# I need help solving a riddle

Tags: riddle

Hi there I would like some help with solving this riddle please if your willing to do so. The riddle is:

> Tell every xeon this.
>   This hiss is sick.
>   None under money but ears run.

The only hint I've gotten is "order".

Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: Hello! Can you add the source of the riddle? :)

Answer (score 12):

The first letter of each word in that riddle says

> TEXT THIS NUMBER...

The only question is,

> Do you know what number to text? Perhaps it is 67337, the standard phone keypad numeric translation for "ORDER"....?